# Android MediaStore playlists members returning wrong Album ID

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

Im using the below function that takes a playlist id and returns the tracks that belongs to that playlist.

```
 public Track[] findTracksByPlaylistId(Context context, Long id) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String playListRef = "content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists/" + id + "/members";
    Uri songUri = Uri.parse(playListRef);
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, PLAYLIST_COLUMNS, null, null, null);
    Track[] tracks = new Track[cursor.getCount()];

    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID);
    int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST);
    int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE);
    int trackColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TRACK);
    int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DURATION);
    int albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM_ID);

    int index = 0;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Track track = new Track(cursor.getInt(idColumn));
        track.setTitle(cursor.getString(titleColumn));
        track.setArtist(cursor.getString(artistColumn));
        track.setDuration(cursor.getInt(durationColumn));
        track.setTrackNumber(cursor.getInt(trackColumn));
        track.setAlbumId(cursor.getLong(albumColumn));
        Log.d(TAG, "ALBUM:" + track.getAlbumId());
        tracks[index++] = track;
    }

    cursor.close();
    return tracks;
}
```

It seems to be returning the wrong album ids. What am i missing?

Comment: I compared your code with one of my routines and your code looks ok. However you have cursor.getlong(albumColumn) whereas I have cursor.getstring.

Comment: I believe ids are supposed to be long, have to tried long instead of int for playlist id?